# Restart remote machine

Tags: remote-access

We have a remote machine , in which winlog shell has set custom application say *myapp.exe*.
So the desktop is not able to view , It is completely blue screen. To access the explorer window, we can do RDP and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> and get taskmanager.
But for some reason <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> not working. So wanted to restart the machine from the local machine from command prompt. I have its openvpn IP (example : 1.2.3.4) and machine name as, for ex: aa-bb-stn1. Also i know the credentials of this machine.
I have tried below command,

```
shutdown -m \\aa-bb-stn1 -r
```

which gave me access denied.

But it didn't helped me out. How to use a command if we can provide with credentials.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please Try The following

ping 192.168.147.232

"shutdown -r -f -m \\192.168.147.232 -u USER -p PASSWORD"

And let me know if it works

Comment: It says access denied

Comment: Please add 2 "\\"

Comment: So it will be "shutdown -r -m \\192.168.147.232"

Comment: Can you Ping the host ?? "ping 123.123.123.123"

Comment: Yes, i had given \\. Also ping is working.

Comment: Please Try this  "shutdown -r -f -m \\192.168.147.232"

Comment: Try this please "shutdown -r -f -m \\192.168.147.232 -u USER -p PASSWORD"

Answer (score 0):

While logged in using RDP, try ctrl+alt+end, this will mimic ctrl+alt+delete on the machine. From there, you can choose to shut down the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PSexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). You'll never want to use another tool ever again!

`psexec \\host -u user cmd` to get a shell, then just `shutdown -r -t 0` to immediately reboot once you have a shell.